# How does Spark passing Scala object to map transformation

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I not sure how Spark passing object to executor, so I wrote this for test. (runs in 1 executor)

In executor, `z`'s init value is 100, although I've set it to 0 in driver. And during the four `map` function, its value keeps growing without reset to 100. The modification of changing `z` to 1000 is also ignored by executor.

Why does this happen? How does Spark passing object to `map` transformer?

```scala
object main extends App {
  val a = sc.parallelize((0 until 10).toList)
  A.z = 0
  println(a.map(x=>A.kk()).collect().mkString(","))
  println(a.map(x=>A.kk()).collect().mkString(","))
  println(s"driver z: ${A.z}")
  A.z=1000
  println("change z to 1000")
  println(a.map(x=>A.kk()).collect().mkString(","))
  println(a.map(x=>A.kk()).collect().mkString(","))
}

object A{
  var z =100
  def kk(): Int ={
    z+=1
    z
  }
}
```

The output is

```
104,105,101,102,103,106,107,108,109,110
114,115,111,112,113,116,117,118,119,120
driver z: 0
change z to 1000
121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130
131,133,132,134,135,136,137,138,139,140
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to manipulate an object which is passed from the Driver to the Executors (it doesn't matter whether you have 1 Executor or N) you have to use an Accumulator.

Spark doesn't pass the object which is manipulated in the Driver, it serializes the original one (which is your 'z=100', no matter the changes).
Also, all changes which are made to the object within the Executors will not be visible in the Driver.

Try:

```
// Driver
val acc = sparkSession.sparkContext.longAccumulator("foo")

// Executor/s
acc.add(...)
acc.reset()
```

Please be advised that each Executor has its own copy of the Accumulator. Once you perform an Action to the Dataset the 'merge' function will be invoked.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#accumulators

Comment: Does driver only serialize original object and pass it to executor only once, as executors's `z` keeps growing? I think Spark should try to serializes variables in `map` function for 4 times, is this a special condition for object?

Comment: It will serialize the ORIGINAL object each time it uses it (meaning, its initialization phase). If you want it to be in sync with the Executors, try Accumulators. If you want it to be initialized in each Executor, use lazy evaluation.

Comment: If it serialize four time, why `z` not begins from 100 in 2nd-4th output?

Comment: The Executors get the object in its current state each time, this is why it does increment from 100 thru 140. I wasn't talking about the serialization between the Driver and the Executors, I was talking about the serialization between the Executors and the Driver. Notice how it prints "driver z: 0" after the Executors have changed its value. This is because the Driver has its own "replicated" value of A and it's not going to be modified. If you want it to be modified by the Executors, you must use Accumulators.

Comment: By the way, I ran it and the Executors get the new value of z=1000 (1000, 1002 ...). The problem starts when you have to use a class instead of an object (serde issues), say that you're using a sealed open-source or even a non-serializable object. This is why it's best to use Accumulators. You can create one yourself, it doesn't have to be of a primitive type.

Comment: Thank you.I know I should not write code like this. Just curious why `z`’s value is so strange.

Comment: Glad that I could help. Take a look at this https://gist.github.com/girisandeep/35b21cca890157afe0084a9e400e2e70 . You can create your own custom Accumulator :)